# Cook and Felderman analysis to perform data reduction on heated surfaces

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

This is a "pain", but I wonder if I can get any real speedup with the follow Python script - it is taking well over 10 minutes to calculate the way it is written now. (And that's only when feeding around 1-2 promille of the data).

I have an with shape (roughly): [260, 300, 300]

Now I am doing a cougar=feldermann analysis on this:

```
import numpy as np
import math
#COOK AND FELDERMAN
def CandF(dT, time, rho, c, k):
    sqrt = np.sqrt
    sumdata=np.zeros(len(time))
    for n in range(len(time)):    
        for data in range(1,n+1):
            sumdata[n] += dT[data] / (sqrt(time[n]-time[data])+sqrt(time[n]-time[data-1]))

    qs = (2*sqrt(rho*c*k))/(sqrt(math.pi)) * sumdata
    return qs

def data_reduction_constant_time(dT, timestep, rho, cp, k):
    #print (len(dT), timestep)
    time = np.linspace(0, len(dT)*timestep, int(len(dT)))
    return data_reduction(dT, time, rho, cp, k )

def data_reduction(dT, time, rho, cp, k):
    return CandF(dT, time, rho, cp, k)

class data:
    def __init__(self):
        #normally lots of file reading

        self.integration = 400
        self.cols = 320
        self.rows = 260
        self.depth = 300
        self.readData()

    def readData(self):
        self.ml_delta_temp = 3 * np.random.random_sample((self.cols, self.rows, self.depth))

    def calcQML(self):
        print("--- Calculating q ---")
        print (self.cols, self.rows, self.depth)
        v = np.zeros([self.cols,self.rows,self.depth])
        T = 590
        P = 28 * 100000
        R = 287
        c = 1005
        k = 1.4
        q = 20
        rho = P/(R*T)  
        print(v)

        print("-------------")
        for x in range(self.cols ):
            print ("calculating column: ", x)
            for y in range(self.rows ):
                v_tmp = data_reduction_constant_time(self.ml_delta_temp[x,y,:], 
                                                                self.integration,
                                                                rho, c, k)
                v[x,y,:] = v_tmp
        print("--- q done ---")
        print(v)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    dat = data()
    dat.calcQML()
```

`self.ml_delta_temp` is a `(260, 300, 300)` shaped numpy array. `cols`, and `rows` are the size of the array, and `integration` is the step size (how much time is between each 3rd axis slice).

Now the problem is: on my computer it takes almost a minute to calculate **a single row**.

How can I speed it up, or as the same question: in what part is this function losing the most time?

I can show the mathematical formula for the Cook and Felderman equation:

$$qCF = \frac{2\sqrt{\rho ck}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{T_i-T_{i-1}}{\sqrt{t_n-t_i}+\sqrt{t_n-t_{i+1}}}$$

<sub>Berry, S.A. and Horvath, T.J. Discrete
Roughness Transition for Hypersonic Flight Vehicles. *Journal of Spacecraft and Rockets*, 2:216{
227, March-April 2008. DOI 10.2514/1.30970.</sub>

Now this is to get the total heat at time "t_n", I am however interested in the heat flux profile, how it changes over time. So I need to calculate this formula for each n. Also I do know not T, but only delta-T (but as one can see that is only beneficial).

Comment: Something seems wrong with `CandF()`: `sumdata[n]` is invariant in the most inner loop, so it is overwritten (n-1) times - ? Could you please describe why you calculate (n-1) values and only keep 1?

Comment: OK, got it: should be `sumdata[n] += dT[data] / (np.sqrt(...`. To save some time you should declare local functions to spare module lookups: `sqrt = np.sqrt` and then use `sqrt()` within `CandF()`.

Comment: @user1016274 what do you mean only keep 1? When you multiply a scalar with an array you do generate an element wise multiplication.

Comment: @user1016274 and here is the cook and felderman formula.

Comment: This is difficult to answer without even having a runnable program to profile. Can you post the **full code** and a description of the inputs you're using (even if it's just "each value in  `delta_temp` is between some lower and upper bound, so random data can be generated as input).

Comment: In your original code for `CandF()` there is no '+' operator! The most inner loop should build up a sum but it doesn't. Do you see it now?

Comment: The formula shown is slightly wrong: the second square root's argument should be `t(n) - t(i-1)` or else element `t(n+1)` would be used as the last element when i==n. Fortunately, you've got it right in the code! For a confirmation, see e.g. here: http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-11152000-08450020/unrestricted/Chap2b.pdf

Comment: @Yuushi - and done

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following replacement for function `CandF()`:

```
def CandF3(dT, time, fac):
sqrt = np.sqrt
sumdata = np.zeros(len(time))
for n in range(len(time)):
    tn = time[n]
    # precompute sqrt(tn-time[0])
    last_sq = sqrt(tn - time[0])
    sum_n = 0
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        sq_j = sqrt(tn - time[j])
        sum_n += dT[j] / (sq_j + last_sq)
        last_sq = sq_j
    sumdata[n] = sum_n
return sumdata * fac
```

The most rewarding idea here was that from the 2 square roots per innermost loop one is the second is computed repeatedly and can be saved for the next loop (here: `last_sq`). Halving the number of `np.sqrt()` calls nearly halves the runtime for large numbers of time steps (`len(time)`).
More optimizations are the use of a local variable for a loop-invariant (`tn`), use of a scalar when indexed variable is not indexed incrementally (`sum_n`), and precomputing the final constant `sqrt(rho*c*k*2.0)` in the caller. This seems natural as the contributing constants are all defined there.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want to try and avoid looping over things as much as possible when working with data like this. The more you can break things into operations on entire arrays/matrices, the faster it will be, generally thanks to SIMD.

Clearly, most of the time is being spent in the `CandF` function, so this is where time would be best spent optimizing.

Using array and matrix primitives instead of looping inside this function gives a roughly ~45x speedup on my machine:

```
def CandF(dT, time, rho, c, k):
    sqrt = np.sqrt
    sumdata=np.zeros(len(time))
    for n in xrange(len(time)):
        z = np.repeat(time[n], n)
        sumdata[n] = np.sum(dT[1:n+1] / (sqrt(z - time[1:n+1]) + sqrt(z - time[0:n])))

    qs = (2*sqrt(rho*c*k))/(sqrt(math.pi)) * sumdata
    return qs
```

Potentially you could squeeze out some more performance by recognizing that the calculation of `np.sqrt(z - time[1:n+1])` calculates almost everything you need for `sqrt(z - time[0:n]))` (only difference is the first value, and the rest of the values need to be shifted by one), but hopefully the above gets you started at least.